# GSAP ScrollTrigger not working as intended

Tags: javascript, gsap, scrolltrigger, locomotive-scroll

I'm trying a simple ScrollTrigger animation where my text would move at the x-axis as I scroll. However, it just doesn't move at all.

HTML:

```
<p class="mountain-text">Mountain</p>
```

CSS:

```
.mountain-text {
     position: relative;
     top: -200px;
     right: -900px;
     font-size: 40px;
}
```

JS:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.0/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script>
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

        gsap.to('.mountain-text', {
            scrollTrigger: {
                trigger: '.mountain-text',
                scrub: true,
                markers: true
            },
            x: 200,
            duration: 2
        });
</script>
```

This is the first time I'm using GSAP but this should be simple enough. I am also using locomotive.js but I don't know if that would affect it.

Comment: It's unclear if you're using `ScrollTrigger` with `Locomotive-Scroll` as the latter is only mentioned in passing in the tags. If `Locomotive-Scroll` is also in use, refer to the answer by @Zach Saucier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use Locomotive Scroll and ScrollTrigger together you need to set up a `.scrollerProxy()` and hook things up as [the documentation](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger/static.scrollerProxy()) covers. There's even [an example demo](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/1dc38ca14811bc76e25c4b8c686b653d) that shows how to do so with Locomotive Scroll.

Comment: His sample code doesn't show `Locomotive-Scroll` being used at all.

Comment: The text in the question includes "I am also using locomotive.js but I don't know if that would affect it." so I addressed it in my answer.